# Generate container from class memebers

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, stl, stl-algorithm

I am wondering if there is an algorithm in the std library which is able to convert a container containing a class type into another container holding a member of that class type.

So what I am basically looking for is an STL alternative for a function like copy_acces in the code below:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class Accessor>
OutputIterator copy_acces(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                          OutputIterator result, Accessor acc) 
{
    while (first!=last) {
        *result = acc(*first);
        ++result;
        ++first;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int i;    
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> vecA = {{0}, {1}, {2}};
    vector<int> vecInt;

    copy_acces(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), 
               back_insert_iterator< vector<int> >(vecInt), 
               [](A a){ return a.i; });

    for(int i : vecInt) {
        cout << i << endl;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something cheap to default construct like an `int` I would use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) like this:

```
std::vector<int> vecInt(vecA.size());
std::transform(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), vecInt.begin(), [](const A& a){ return a.i; });
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M4AQfgLOQbWfam7X).

For something that is not default constructible or expensive to default construct you can't or won't want to construct a vector of the right size first. You can still use `std::transform` with a `back_inserter` but I start to think that a simple ranged-based for loop is easier to read:

```
std::vector<ExpensiveToConstruct> vecB;
vecB.reserve(vecA.size());

for (const auto& a : vecA) {
    vecB.push_back(a.e);
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6j7MLZVFZpV8vbrX).

Comment: why does the cheapness matter? If OP wants to have the members in the vector they need to copy them anyhow

Comment: @tobi303 because I am constructing a vector if `int` of the required size and then overwriting. For something expensive to default construct it would be better to reserve and then use a back_inserter which I might add as an alternative...

Comment: @ChrisDrew if I get that right, the cheapness is no criteria for using std::transform but rather for using back_inserter, right?

Comment: @exlit, Well, yes, but the need to use a back_inserter makes it more tempting to just use a loop rather than `std::transform`.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/), like this for example:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::transform
#include <vector>       // std::vector

using namespace std;

struct A {
    int i;    
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> vecA = {{0}, {1}, {2}};
    vector<int> vecInt;

    vecInt.resize(vecA.size());
    std::transform (vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), vecInt.begin(), [](A a){ return a.i; });

    for(int i : vecInt) {
        cout << i << endl;   
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: Hmm, I looked at std::transform before, but could not get my head around how to apply that to my solution. Could have been enough to look at the equivalent implementation at www.cplusplus.com.

Comment: It's OK @exilit, glad that I helped!